# start more than one async task on android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I want to start 2 async task's, but only one get executed. The output of LogCat should be something like:

```
firstAsync started
secondAsync started
secondAsync ends
firstAsync ends
end
```

but the output of LogCat is

```
firstAsync started
end
```

it shows that the secondAsync were never been executed.
Here is the java code:

```
package com.example.async;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.app.Activity;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public boolean stopAsync=false;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        new firstAsync().execute();
        new secondAsync().execute();
        Log.e("end","end");
    }

    class firstAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            Log.e("firstAsync started","firstAsync started");
            while(!stopAsync)
            {

            }
            Log.e("firstAsync ends","firstAsync ends");
            return null;
        }
    }

    class secondAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            Log.e("secondAsync started","secondAsync started");
            stopAsync = true;
            Log.e("secondAsync ends","secondAsync ends");
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

so, the question is, how can I start multiple async task's, hope you can help me.
regards
chris

Comment: `AsyncTask`s **always** execute one at a time: ["Starting with HONEYCOMB, tasks are executed on a single thread to avoid common application errors caused by parallel execution."](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: @user113215 You should post this and the next sentence "If you truly want parallel execution, you can invoke `executeOnExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor, Object[])` with `THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR`." as an answer.

Comment: What happens if you put one async in the other? Just asking, is that even possible?

Answer (score 4):

[`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)s always execute one at a time, unless you use `executeOnExecutor()`:

> AsyncTask is designed to be a helper class around `Thread` and `Handler` and does not constitute a generic threading framework.
>
> **Starting with `HONEYCOMB`, tasks are executed on a single thread to
>   avoid common application errors caused by parallel execution.** If you
>   truly want parallel execution, you can invoke
>   `executeOnExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor, Object[])` with
>   `THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR`.

Comment: "The best advice is not to use AsyncTasks when you need parallel execution" -- why? Android uses `AsyncTask` for parallel execution itself, using `THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR`, for things like the `Loader` framework.

Comment: @CommmonsWare I'm imagining that the length/complexity of the tasks to be run in parallel will typically exceed what `AsyncTask` was designed for: quick (a few seconds), one-time operations.

Comment: :: shrug :: I fail to see where parallelism ties inextricably to complexity. I would agree that long-running work should not be done via an `AsyncTask`. I'll even go so far as to say that `AsyncTask` is probably overused. But there are plenty of bits of transactional work (e.g., downloading/parsing JSON feeds, loading and resampling images from disk) that are not especially complex but can run well in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

This is interesting

In this I put a second async within the first to start on preexecute. The logcat and code shows it best:

My log cat:

```
12-29 21:53:35.661: E/Async1: being executed
12-29 21:53:35.661: E/Async1: executing
12-29 21:53:35.661: E/Async2: being started
12-29 21:53:35.669: E/Async2: backgrounding
12-29 21:53:35.669: E/Async1: backgrounding
12-29 21:53:35.676: E/Async2: finishing
12-29 21:53:35.676: E/Async1: finishing
```

For the following code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Log.e("Async1", "being executed");
    new Async1().execute();
}

public class Async1 extends AsyncTask {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Log.e("Async1", "executing");
        Log.e("Async2", "being started");
        new Async2().execute();
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.e("Async1", "finishing");
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... arg0) {
        Log.e("Async1", "backgrounding");
        return null;
    }

    public class Async2 extends AsyncTask {

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
            Log.e("Async2", "finishing");
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
            Log.e("Async2", "backgrounding");
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting. What Android version are you using? According to the docs, `AsyncTask`s will automatically load on the UI thread as of `JELLY_BEAN`, which makes me think this might not result in parallel execution on Android 4.1+?

Comment: 4.2 on the Galaxy Nexus, stock rom.

Comment: The questions are what are the implications of this? I mean you don't even know what order things are going to run in at all... also can you keep going to Async5million (hypothetically of course, I doubt anyone will ever need more than 4 million)

Answer (score 0):

on the onPostExecute() method of the first AsyncTask, start the second AsyncTask

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    if (result!=null)
    //start the Second asyncTask
    new secondAsync().execute();
}
```

Comment: This will never happen since `firstAsync` won't call `onPostExecute()` until `secondAsync` starts.

Comment: I already implmented something like above in one of my Solution

Comment: I understand that your AsyncTasks might work like this, but user1836363's doesn't. Look closer at both `doInBackground()` methods and notice that `stopAsync` only changes to `true` in `secondAsync`...